# Creating table from internal stage data is Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have followed the process of putting my data I need in a table from a file into an internal stage using SnowSQL. The data is there all ok, however when I go to insert it into a table it fails for a number of reasons such as "values exceeding column 1 maximum value". Basically my column is varchar(20) and there is a record in the data that is 25 or something. Gives error User character length limit (20) exceeded by string for pretty much all the fields. There are about 100 columns, so is there a way to create the table from scratch using the stage data?

For example I would use

create table *table1* as
select * from *@mystageddata*

but it doesn't seem to like that? Is there a way to make that kind of thing work, so that the table accepts all values without me having to tweak every column?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data format inside stage is Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, or ORC then the fastest way to create table's structure is
[INFER_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema) and [CREATE TABLE … USING TEMPLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-using-template):

> Creates a new table with the column definitions derived from a set of staged files containing semi-structured data. This feature is currently limited to Apache Parquet, Apache Avro, and ORC files.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable
>  USING TEMPLATE (
>    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
>    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDER_ID)
>      FROM TABLE(
>        INFER_SCHEMA(
>          LOCATION=>'@mystage',
>          FILE_FORMAT=>'my_parquet_format'
>        )
>      ));
> ```

Data loading has to be performed separately.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, will investigate. If its the case that the data is not in Apache or ORC, does that mean I am just out of luck?

Comment: @MikeLanglois Not necesarilly. `CREATE TABLE my_table AS SELECT $1::data_type AS alias_1, $2::daty_type AS alias_2, ..., $100::data_type AS alias_100 FROM  ...`. More at: [Querying Data in Staged Files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage)